# Which One Is More Efficient Using Material Or Sprite As Object Picture Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We know that when import png, jpg file to unity there will be a import setting in the inspector which is tell to set Texture type as Texture, Sprite, Cursor, Advanced and soon. It will have a Max Size compression too.

BUT,

In Creating 2D games

I wonder which one is more effecient and effective to reduce a size of the file game apk using Material as (background picture, gameobject picture, UI picture) OR using sprite as (background picture, gameobject picture, UI picture) ???

Also that is there a way to pack all sprite image to reduce the size when export as APK ? Because i am developing the 2D Games and i don't want to make a game with big file size. I need to reduce a size as small as possible.

**Edited :**

So how to reduce a file size escpecially for image in game to the possible minimum size ?

How to reduce a build size apk to the minimum size ?

I wonder is if there is a different using MATERIAL OR SPRITE in reduce size ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: *"Which One Is More Efficient Using Material Or Sprite As Background Picture Or Object Picture Unity3D"*... Your question is not clear. Please give example of each way you just mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Programmer I have edited and explain it more detail. Is that clear the answer ?

Comment: You can place all your sprite together in one file and use the Sprite Editor to cut them in Unity. This won't reduce the size, just the draw call. Instead of many small pics, you have one big. Reducing the size of a pic is either making it physically smaller (512x512 to 256x256 is 4 times smaller in size), you can also make sure there is no generated mip maps.

Comment: Hi @Everts Why my image file is 1.6 MB when imported to unity and setting to sprite the size become 9.0 MB but when i compress to max size 2048 mb nothing compress the file size still 9.0 MB ?

Comment: What is the differrent between Sprite and Material ? What should i use for UI sprite to reduce file size ?

Comment: A Sprite used for 2D rendering, basically it is a quad with a picture with a SpriteRenderer. A material is a class used in the Renderer to affect the rendering. It contains reference to shader and texture and others. You can attach one or many materials to a MeshRenderer or a SpriteRenderer. When you compress to 2048 it does not do anything possibly coz your image is already smaller.

Comment: Hi@Everts Why original size file only 1.6 MB when importing to unity and set texture type to sprite it become larger like 4.5 MB ?

Comment: The question you asked is wrong. it doesn't matter if it's sprite or anything else. The compression method is what changes the size of APK. try 16 bit and no mip maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Far As Size of An APK is concerned using textures and materials don't add that much size as compared to sprite.

Unity Provides a lot of compression techniques for textures so there is a big area in which one can tweak the compression as far as the size and look of game is concerned.

Sprites are imported in their actual form without any compression and they also have defined types of compressions.

So using Texture will be a good idea if reducing the size of APK is concerned